# When one item is open in the nav, close all others width jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation that is opened/closed with jQuery. And I tried to make it so that when you click eg. Item 2 if any other items are opened it should close them. But now I can't close Item 2.

```
$(document).ready(

function () {
    $('a.has-child').click(function () {
        $('div.child').not(this).removeClass("open");
        $(this).closest('li').find('div.child').addClass("open");
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwcq0yek/

UPDATE: I am able to open Item 4 and close Item 2 and vice versa. But I can't close Item 2 or Item 3 alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove class to all `.child`.

```
$('div.child').removeClass("open");
```

Then add class open to the clicked element

```
$(this).closest('li').find('div.child').addClass("open");
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mwcq0yek/5/)

**update**

You need to do a test if you want to close the `.child` submenu. What you need is to test, if that submenu has a class `open` or not.

```
    if ( submenu.hasClass("open") ) {
        submenu.removeClass("open");
    } else {
        $('div.child').removeClass("open");
        submenu.addClass("open");
    }
```

[**updated demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mwcq0yek/7/)

Comment: I am sorry I did not mention but I need the eg. Item 2 to close alone. I open the menu and look at items, open other menu look at items and when I'm finished I want to close the menu. But I can't close it.